# Issue with Transforming CSV Data and Matching Symbols for ggsankey Input in R

Tags: r, csv

I am currently facing a challenge while attempting to transform CSV data for visualization with the ggsankey package in R. My goal is to create a new DataFrame from the data stored in a CSV file, where I can match symbols between species. The DataFrame should have the following columns: "x", "node", "next_x", and "next_node". In this context, "x" represents the species name, "node" represents the current symbol, "next_x" represents the subsequent species name, and "next_node" should correspond to the matching symbol in the subsequent species.

This is my CSV data:

```
species symbol start stop orientation
Homo_sapiens SLC35A1 1 2 1
Homo_sapiens RARS2 2 3 -1
Homo_sapiens ORC3 3 4 1
Homo_sapiens AKIRIN2 4 5 -1
Homo_sapiens SPACA1 5 6 1
Homo_sapiens CNR1 6 7 -1
Homo_sapiens RNGTT 7 8 -1
Homo_sapiens PNRC1 8 9 1
Homo_sapiens PM20D2 9 10 1
Homo_sapiens SRSF12 10 11 -1
Homo_sapiens GABRR1 11 12 -1
Mus_musculus GABRR1 1 2 1
Mus_musculus PM20D2 2 3 -1
Mus_musculus SRSF12 3 4 1
Mus_musculus PNRC1 4 5 -1
Mus_musculus RNGTT 5 6 1
Mus_musculus CNR1 6 7 1
Mus_musculus SPACA1 7 8 -1
Mus_musculus AKIRIN2 8 9 1
Mus_musculus ORC3 9 10 -1
Mus_musculus RARS2 10 11 1
Mus_musculus SLC35A1 11 12 -1
Rattus_norvegicus GABRR1 1 2 1
Rattus_norvegicus PM20D2 2 3 -1
Rattus_norvegicus SRSF12 3 4 1
Rattus_norvegicus PNRC1 4 5 -1
Rattus_norvegicus RNGTT 5 6 1
Rattus_norvegicus CNR1 6 7 1
Rattus_norvegicus SPACA1 7 8 -1
Rattus_norvegicus AKIRIN2 8 9 1
Rattus_norvegicus ORC3 9 10 -1
Rattus_norvegicus RARS2 10 11 1
Rattus_norvegicus SLC35A1 11 12 -1
Canis_lupus_familiaris SLC35A1 1 2 1
Canis_lupus_familiaris RARS2 2 3 -1
Canis_lupus_familiaris ORC3 3 4 1
Canis_lupus_familiaris AKIRIN2 4 5 -1
Canis_lupus_familiaris SPACA1 5 6 1
Canis_lupus_familiaris CNR1 6 7 -1
Canis_lupus_familiaris RNGTT 7 8 -1
Canis_lupus_familiaris PNRC1 8 9 1
Canis_lupus_familiaris SRSF12 9 10 -1
Canis_lupus_familiaris PM20D2 10 11 1
Canis_lupus_familiaris GABRR1 11 12 -1
Monodelphis_domestica SLC35A1 1 2 1
Monodelphis_domestica RARS2 2 3 -1
Monodelphis_domestica ORC3 3 4 1
Monodelphis_domestica AKIRIN2 4 5 -1
Monodelphis_domestica SPACA1 5 6 1
Monodelphis_domestica CNR1 6 7 -1
Monodelphis_domestica RNGTT 7 8 -1
Monodelphis_domestica PNRC1 8 9 1
Monodelphis_domestica SRSF12 9 10 -1
Monodelphis_domestica PM20D2 10 11 1
Monodelphis_domestica GABRR1 11 12 -1
Ornithorhynchus_anatinus SLC35A1 1 2 1
Ornithorhynchus_anatinus RARS2 2 3 -1
Ornithorhynchus_anatinus ORC3 3 4 1
Ornithorhynchus_anatinus AKIRIN2 4 5 -1
Ornithorhynchus_anatinus SPACA1 5 6 1
Ornithorhynchus_anatinus CNR1 6 7 -1
Ornithorhynchus_anatinus RNGTT 7 8 -1
Ornithorhynchus_anatinus PNRC1 8 9 1
Ornithorhynchus_anatinus PM20D2 9 10 1
Ornithorhynchus_anatinus LOC100076186 10 11 -1
Ornithorhynchus_anatinus LOC114805750 11 12 1
Gallus_gallus PM20D2 1 2 -1
Gallus_gallus PNRC1 2 3 -1
Gallus_gallus BORCS6 3 4 1
Gallus_gallus RNGTT 4 5 1
Gallus_gallus LOC101749895 5 6 1
Gallus_gallus CNR1 6 7 1
Gallus_gallus SPACA1 7 8 -1
Gallus_gallus AKIRIN2 8 9 1
Gallus_gallus ORC3 9 10 -1
Gallus_gallus RARS2 10 11 1
Gallus_gallus SLC35A1 11 12 -1
Taeniopygia_guttata CFAP206 1 2 1
Taeniopygia_guttata SLC35A1 2 3 1
Taeniopygia_guttata RARS2 3 4 -1
Taeniopygia_guttata ORC3 4 5 1
Taeniopygia_guttata AKIRIN2 5 6 -1
Taeniopygia_guttata CNR1 6 7 -1
Taeniopygia_guttata RNGTT 7 8 -1
Taeniopygia_guttata BORCS6 8 9 -1
Taeniopygia_guttata PNRC1 9 10 1
Taeniopygia_guttata PM20D2 10 11 1
Taeniopygia_guttata GABRR1 11 12 -1
Chelonia_mydas SLC35A1 1 2 1
Chelonia_mydas RARS2 2 3 -1
Chelonia_mydas ORC3 3 4 1
Chelonia_mydas AKIRIN2 4 5 -1
Chelonia_mydas SPACA1 5 6 1
Chelonia_mydas CNR1 6 7 -1
Chelonia_mydas RNGTT 7 8 -1
Chelonia_mydas LOC102938330 8 9 -1
Chelonia_mydas PNRC1 9 10 1
Chelonia_mydas PM20D2 10 11 1
Chelonia_mydas GABRR1 11 12 -1
Anolis_carolinensis PM20D2 1 2 -1
Anolis_carolinensis SRSF12 2 3 1
Anolis_carolinensis PNRC1 3 4 -1
Anolis_carolinensis RNGTT 4 5 1
Anolis_carolinensis LOC107982676 5 6 -1
Anolis_carolinensis CNR1 6 7 1
Anolis_carolinensis SPACA1 7 8 -1
Anolis_carolinensis AKIRIN2 8 9 1
Anolis_carolinensis ORC3 9 10 -1
Anolis_carolinensis RARS2 10 11 1
Anolis_carolinensis SLC35A1 11 12 -1
Xenopus_laevis GABRR2.S 1 2 1
Xenopus_laevis GABRR1.S 2 3 1
Xenopus_laevis PM20D2.S 3 4 -1
Xenopus_laevis LOC108717975 4 5 1
Xenopus_laevis RNGTT.S 5 6 1
Xenopus_laevis CNR1.S 6 7 1
Xenopus_laevis AKIRIN2.S 7 8 1
Xenopus_laevis ORC3.S 8 9 -1
Xenopus_laevis RARS2.S 9 10 1
Xenopus_laevis SLC35A1.S 10 11 -1
Xenopus_laevis LOC108717977 11 12 1
Latimeria_chalumnae DDX24 1 2 -1
Latimeria_chalumnae PPP4R4 2 3 1
Latimeria_chalumnae SERPINA10B 3 4 -1
Latimeria_chalumnae ARRDC3A 4 5 1
Latimeria_chalumnae LOC102360869 5 6 -1
Latimeria_chalumnae CNR1 6 7 1
Latimeria_chalumnae SPACA1 7 8 -1
Latimeria_chalumnae AKIRIN2 8 9 1
Latimeria_chalumnae ORC3 9 10 -1
Latimeria_chalumnae RARS2 10 11 1
Latimeria_chalumnae LOC102362557 11 12 1
Protopterus_annectens LOC122794922 1 2 1
Protopterus_annectens LOC122794923 2 3 1
Protopterus_annectens LOC122794924 3 4 1
Protopterus_annectens FBXL5 4 5 1
Protopterus_annectens CC2D2A 5 6 -1
Protopterus_annectens CNR1 6 7 1
Protopterus_annectens CPEB2 7 8 -1
Protopterus_annectens BOD1L1 8 9 -1
Protopterus_annectens C1QTNF7 9 10 -1
Protopterus_annectens NKX3-2 10 11 1
Protopterus_annectens RAB28 11 12 1
Danio_rerio MYO6A 1 2 1
Danio_rerio LOC569340 2 3 -1
Danio_rerio MEI4 3 4 1
Danio_rerio NT5E 4 5 1
Danio_rerio SNX14 5 6 -1
Danio_rerio CNR1 6 7 -1
Danio_rerio RNGTT 7 8 -1
Danio_rerio PNRC1 8 9 1
Danio_rerio GABRR1 9 10 -1
Danio_rerio GABRR2B 10 11 -1
Danio_rerio UBE2J1 11 12 -1
Oreochromis_niloticus SI:DKEY-174M14.3 1 2 1
Oreochromis_niloticus RDH14B 2 3 -1
Oreochromis_niloticus LOC102078481 3 4 1
Oreochromis_niloticus RNGTT 4 5 1
Oreochromis_niloticus LOC112842425 5 6 -1
Oreochromis_niloticus CNR1 6 7 1
Oreochromis_niloticus AKIRIN2 7 8 1
Oreochromis_niloticus RARS2 8 9 1
Oreochromis_niloticus SLC35A1 9 10 -1
Oreochromis_niloticus LOC100692709 10 11 -1
Oreochromis_niloticus LOC102081816 11 12 1
Scyliorhinus_canicula SLC35A1 1 2 1
Scyliorhinus_canicula RARS2 2 3 -1
Scyliorhinus_canicula ORC3 3 4 1
Scyliorhinus_canicula AKIRIN2 4 5 -1
Scyliorhinus_canicula LOC119967921 5 6 1
Scyliorhinus_canicula CNR1 6 7 -1
Scyliorhinus_canicula RNGTT 7 8 -1
Scyliorhinus_canicula LOC119967175 8 9 -1
Scyliorhinus_canicula PNRC1 9 10 1
Scyliorhinus_canicula LOC119967178 10 11 1
Scyliorhinus_canicula LOC119967180 11 12 -1
Petromyzon_marinus LOC116953416 1 2 -1
Petromyzon_marinus LOC116953419 2 3 -1
Petromyzon_marinus CEP162 3 4 1
Petromyzon_marinus FBXL22 4 5 -1
Petromyzon_marinus RNGTT 5 6 1
Petromyzon_marinus CNR1 6 7 1
Petromyzon_marinus AKIRIN2 7 8 1
Petromyzon_marinus ORC3 8 9 -1
Petromyzon_marinus RARS2 9 10 1
Petromyzon_marinus SLC35A1 10 11 -1
Petromyzon_marinus RHBDL2 11 12 1
```

To accomplish this, I have written the following code, which I believe should produce the desired output:

```
library(dplyr)

# Read the CSV data
data <- read.csv("cnr1.csv")

# Create a new DataFrame with the desired columns
new_data <- data.frame(x = character(0), node = character(0), next_x = character(0), next_node = character(0), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Fill the new DataFrame based on the given rules
for (i in 1:(nrow(data) - 1)) {
  row <- data[i, ]
  next_row <- data[i + 1, ]
 
  next_species <- next_row$species
  next_symbol <- next_row$symbol
 
  matching_symbol <- ifelse(next_species == next_row$species, next_symbol, "NA")
 
  new_row <- data.frame(
    x = row$species,
    node = row$symbol,
    next_x = next_species,
    next_node = matching_symbol
  )
 
  new_data <- bind_rows(new_data, new_row)
}

# Add the last row with NA values
last_row <- data[nrow(data), ]
new_data <- bind_rows(new_data, data.frame(
  x = last_row$species,
  node = last_row$symbol,
  next_x = "NA",
  next_node = "NA"
))

# Write the transformed data to a new CSV file
output_filename <- "output.csv"
write.csv(new_data, file = output_filename, row.names = FALSE)
cat(paste("Output written to", output_filename))
```

However, the current output is not as expected. As I get the following output:

```
x,node,next_x,next_node
Homo_sapiens,SLC35A1,Homo_sapiens,NA
Homo_sapiens,RARS2,Homo_sapiens,NA
Homo_sapiens,ORC3,Homo_sapiens,NA
Homo_sapiens,AKIRIN2,Homo_sapiens,NA
Homo_sapiens,SPACA1,Homo_sapiens,NA
Homo_sapiens,CNR1,Homo_sapiens,NA
Homo_sapiens,RNGTT,Homo_sapiens,NA
Homo_sapiens,PNRC1,Homo_sapiens,NA
Homo_sapiens,PM20D2,Homo_sapiens,NA
Homo_sapiens,SRSF12,Homo_sapiens,NA
Homo_sapiens,GABRR1,Mus_musculus,Mus_musculus
Mus_musculus,GABRR1,Mus_musculus,NA
Mus_musculus,PM20D2,Mus_musculus,NA
Mus_musculus,SRSF12,Mus_musculus,NA
Mus_musculus,PNRC1,Mus_musculus,NA
Mus_musculus,RNGTT,Mus_musculus,NA
Mus_musculus,CNR1,Mus_musculus,NA
Mus_musculus,SPACA1,Mus_musculus,NA
Mus_musculus,AKIRIN2,Mus_musculus,NA
Mus_musculus,ORC3,Mus_musculus,NA
Mus_musculus,RARS2,Mus_musculus,NA
Mus_musculus,SLC35A1,Rattus_norvegicus,NA
.
.
.
Petromyzon_marinus,LOC116953416,Petromyzon_marinus,NA
Petromyzon_marinus,LOC116953419,Petromyzon_marinus,NA
Petromyzon_marinus,CEP162,Petromyzon_marinus,NA
Petromyzon_marinus,FBXL22,Petromyzon_marinus,NA
Petromyzon_marinus,RNGTT,Petromyzon_marinus,NA
Petromyzon_marinus,CNR1,Petromyzon_marinus,NA
Petromyzon_marinus,AKIRIN2,Petromyzon_marinus,NA
Petromyzon_marinus,ORC3,Petromyzon_marinus,NA
Petromyzon_marinus,RARS2,Petromyzon_marinus,NA
Petromyzon_marinus,SLC35A1,Petromyzon_marinus,NA
Petromyzon_marinus,RHBDL2,NA,NA
```

The primary issue lies in the assignment of values to the "next_x" and "next_node" columns. These values should be determined by the subsequent species and its associated symbol, but my code seems to be assigning incorrect values. Additionally, for the last species, "next_x" and "next_node" should both be "NA".

The intended output format is as follows:

```
x                   node  next_x              next_node
Homo_sapiens        CNR   Mus_musculus        CNR
Mus_musculus        CNR   Rattus_norvegicus   CNR
.
.
.
Gallus_gallus       LOC101749895   NA         NA
.
.
.
Petromyzon_marinus  RHBDL2 NA      NA
```

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to correct the code to generate the expected output. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Why did you tag python?

Comment: Hi! I appreciate the question! To improve your question and make it useful to others you could skip the `read_csv()` part in the beginning and the `write_csv()` part in the end. Then share the first ten rows of `data` only, you can do this for example by pasting the output of `dput(head(data, 10))` into a code chunk in your question.

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr::lag()` and `dplyr::lead()` are great to get values from the previous
or following row.

The code below replaces everything after the line `data <- read.csv("cnr1.csv")`

```r
data |>
  rename(node = symbol,
         x = species) |>
  mutate(next_node = lead(node),
         next_x = lead(x))
#> # A tibble: 187 × 7
#>    x            node    start  stop orientation next_node next_x      
#>    <chr>        <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>     <chr>       
#>  1 Homo_sapiens SLC35A1     1     2           1 RARS2     Homo_sapiens
#>  2 Homo_sapiens RARS2       2     3          -1 ORC3      Homo_sapiens
#>  3 Homo_sapiens ORC3        3     4           1 AKIRIN2   Homo_sapiens
#>  4 Homo_sapiens AKIRIN2     4     5          -1 SPACA1    Homo_sapiens
#>  5 Homo_sapiens SPACA1      5     6           1 CNR1      Homo_sapiens
#>  6 Homo_sapiens CNR1        6     7          -1 RNGTT     Homo_sapiens
#>  7 Homo_sapiens RNGTT       7     8          -1 PNRC1     Homo_sapiens
#>  8 Homo_sapiens PNRC1       8     9           1 PM20D2    Homo_sapiens
#>  9 Homo_sapiens PM20D2      9    10           1 SRSF12    Homo_sapiens
#> 10 Homo_sapiens SRSF12     10    11          -1 GABRR1    Homo_sapiens
#> # ℹ 177 more rows
```